# siblings not hiding on a jqueryui slide

Tags: jquery-ui

here's the function:

```
$('.popoutlink').on('click', function() {
   var box = $('#' + $(this).data('box'));
   box.siblings().hide();
   box.toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
   box.siblings().hide();
});
```

the two `siblings.hide` statements are because I'm in the middle of trying to figure out why I'm left with two slideouts on screen if I click on two buttons in rapid succession.

The html is:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p1">1</div>
    <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p2">2</div>
    <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p3">3</div>
    <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p4">4</div>
    <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p5">5</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 bb" style="height: 400px;">
    <div class="popout" id="p1"><h1>panel 1</h1></div>
    <div class="popout" id="p2">
        <h1>panel 2</h1>  
    </div>
```

If I click on two buttons quickly then two windows are left on screen. I would like the siblings to hide before the selected div appears.

I have tried using `promise.done()`:

```
box.siblings().hide(200).promise().done(function(){
    box.toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
});
```

to no effect.  Adding `box.toggle` to `hide` as a callback:

```
box.siblings().hide(200, function(){
    box.toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
});
```

was very funny but not useful.

How do I get the siblings to go away reliably before I show the selected div no matter how quickly I click the buttons?

You [see it here](https://jqueryuiexperimentscratchpad-gedq.c9users.io/) just click on the numbered boxes quickly

Thanks

Comment: So on initial click, you want all `.popout` to be hidden, correct? And then, depending on the `.popoutlink` that was clicked, you want that specific one shown?

Comment: Yes.  Or more to the point I want one popout and one only to be showing no matter how quickly I click the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, this should help:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3mbh5p0r/

**jQuery UI**

```
$(function() {
  $('.popoutlink').on('click', function() {
    var box = $('#' + $(this).data('box'));
    $(".popout").hide();
    //box.siblings().hide();
    box.toggle("slide", {
      direction: "left"
    }, 500);
    //box.siblings().hide();
  });
});
```

When any of the "links" are clicked, they are all hidden and then only the one whom was clicked is toggled.

**Update**

---

A little more testing of `.hide()` versus `.css("display", "none")` revealed that changing the CSS was a faster method. This page talks about how it's *immediate* but I found that it wasn't as fast.

> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ),
>   except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's
>   data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value.
>   If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown,
>   it will once again be displayed inline.

And:

> Note that .hide() is fired immediately and will override the animation
>   queue if no duration or a duration of 0 is specified.

I did try using the callback, which made it worse. The callback should be triggered when the hide animation is complete, yet it added the element of animating the hide operation. Even when the speed was 0, it was slower.

So I advise this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.popoutlink').on('click', function() {
    $(".popout").css("display", "none");
    $('#' + $(this).data('box')).show("fast");
  });
});
```

Comment: No, same problem.  Rapid clicking leaves two divs on screen.  Maybe I need to look at slowing down the response.

Comment: How quickly are you clicking?  How often do users do this?

Comment: can't really time it but I'd say about 0.25 seconds. And yes, I know from hard experience that users will click that quickly.

Comment: @gedq I tried to replicate the issue in FireFox and I could not get more than 1 to appear. I single clicked, I double clicked, I clicked and moved as fast as I could... I increase the hide speed to 0: `.hide(0)` and this seemed to increase it's hiding speed. The action of another click event could potentially interrupt the current function, the events should be stacking. What browser are you using, what version of JQ and JQ UI? Be as specific as you can for replication.

Comment: @gedq updated my answer after a little more testing, still unable to replicate the issue as you described. I did find some improvements, that sped things up, and I suspect will help you out.

Comment: It's animation speed - anything over 200ms (I'm using Waterfox on a Windows 10 Trinity A6 and Chrome on a Windows 10 i7, it matches the expected users) and I get glitches.  200 and below and the display is rock solid.  Thank you.